# How to make HTTP request from spesific source IP Address on a server which has multiple IP Addresses?

Tags: c#, .net, http, networking, ip

I hope you well in this pandemic,

We have a server which has **multiple IP Addresses** on it, we want to make HTTP requests **from spesific source IP Address** of that server.

Ex: Server has these ip addresses
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3

We need to send HTTP Request **from** 1.1.1.1 and also we need to send **from** 3.3.3.3 with another instance of HttpClient
So we can be able to set source ip address of http request client

How can we achive that?

We use .NET's **HttpClient** but it's not necessary if it doesn't support, we can use another http request client if exists supporting to set source ip address

Thanks,

Comment: A URL can either be a string name of the machine or the IP address as a string HttpWebRequest.Create("1.1.1.1");

Comment: I want to send from that IP address not request to it

Comment: Some info: Looks like for .netcore progress has been made here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1793. For .net framework you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.bindipendpointdelegate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_ServicePoint_BindIPEndPointDelegate.

Comment: Windows use standard IP routing rules which uses IP and mask to determine the route.  You can also bind the local endpoint to an adapter.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.bind?view=netcore-3.1